# Difference between Viscous stress tensor and Shear stress tensor?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain, viscosity

I am trying to learn about fluid dynamics in the context of **incompressible**, **Newtonian** fluids, **Laminar** flows. Unfortunately, different authors use different notations and every time I found my self very confused about some concepts.

In my knowledge, the total stress tensor: 
 $$ \sigma_{ij} = -p\delta_{ij} + \tau_{ij}$$

Where $\delta_{ij}$ is the kronecker delta, and $p$ is the hydrostatic pressure given by:
  $$p = -{\sigma_{ii}\over 3}$$

My understanding is that the deviatoric tensor, $\tau_{ij}$ is called: **the viscous stress tensor**.

If so, what is the **shear** stress tensor? is it the same name for the viscous stress tensor?

I hope someone could help me clarify this ambiguity.

Comment: They are the same thing, deviatoric tensor, viscous tensor or shear stress tensor. They are different from zero if the 3 principal stresses $\sigma_{ii}$ are not all equal.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski: Any reference?

Comment: I think by shear stress tensor they mean the deviatoric stress tensor.

Answer (score -1):

In my textbook, Physical Hydrodynamics by Guyon, $\sigma_{ij}$ is called the *stress tensor* or I think wiki calls it *Cauchy stress tensor*. $\tau_{ij}$ here is called the *viscous stress tensor* or *viscous shear stress tensor*.

Liquid will flow under shear stress, so still liquid doesn't have shear stress, only stress that's perpendicular to any surface, which is $-p\delta_{ij}$. If we use still liquid as a reference point, the *Cauchy stress tensor* can be divided into this component and an extra component, which involves both the shear stress and the viscosity of the fluid, which is $\tau_{ij}$.

Comment: Could you explain this "Liquid will flow under shear stress, so still liquid doesn't have shear stress,"? what is "still liquid" in "if we use still liquid ..."?

Comment: Sorry, your answer makes me more confused.

Comment: Take a piece of paper and put it on top of the water surface. Use your hand to slide the paper forward and water will flow. Do the same thing on a solid and you would at most deform it into a Parallelepiped. One of the characteristics of liquid is that it doesn't sustain shear force, it flows when you apply shear force.

Comment: Sorry, And how is that related to my question? could you use equations to describe your ideas? I find your language hard for me to follow, if there are equation I will try my best to understand them. Thanks

Comment: It's a motivation for us to use still water as a reference point and define viscous stress tensor as the total stress tensor minus this reference point.

Comment: Please could you just explain what does it mean the expression "**still water**" ? The dictionary gives me nonsense expression.

Comment: water that's not flowing. I'm sorry I don't know how else I should express it.

Comment: Sorry, I've read your answer more than 5 times and still can't make sense of it.

Comment: I mean water at rest, or water where velocity field is 0 everywhere. (Although in general, water without velocity gradient also doesn't have shear stress).